# Why does #define NUM_EMPLOYEES 20; give a syntax error when used?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm getting an error while using the `malloc` function for a pointer:

```
#define NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES 20;    
int *ids;

    ids = malloc(NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES*sizeof(int));
```

the compiler is giving me some errors about conflicting types initialization makes integer from pointer without cast and initializer element is not a constant and data definition has no storage class
please can some one answer me and find out why all these warnings

Comment: Remove the colon at the end:`#define NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES 20`

Comment: You should make sure you post exact error messages. It does help.

Comment: The duplicate question has exactly the same basic scenario: `#define … …;` is almost invariably wrong when there's a semicolon at the end.  There might be an earlier question about the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

```
#define NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES 20; /* Problem here */
```

Remove here the semicolon, it's being interpreted as:

```
ids = malloc(20; * sizeof(int));
               ^ // Here is the semicolon...
```

Comment: It is being interpretted as `ids = malloc(20; * sizeof(int))`?

Comment: @maskacovnik I only wanted to show the semicolon that it's being there, but your comment is also valid.

Comment: it was an error in copying , in the actual code there was no ; after the #define but when i put these lines inside the main() the error disappear

Answer (score 1):

C macro preprocessor don't need to end with semicolon, this is the source of your problem.

Besides, think that you always have to ckeck the value returned by malloc, there might be not enough memory space.

Here's what you want to do :

```
#include <stddef.h>
#define NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES 20

int         main()
{    
    int     *ids;

    if((ids = malloc(NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES * sizeof(int))) == NULL)
    {
        /* handle error */
    }
}
```